# Querying Where date_created without time is same as last_updated without time

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I need to write a query (if possible) that finds all rows of a table where the date_created is the same as last_updated.  The rub is that I need to ignore the time.  Basically, I'm looking for user rows that were created and activated the same day (we don't store an activation date).  So presumably the dates would be the same but the times may be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function, which returns only the date portion of a datetime value. This allows you to compare just the date portion of the values:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE DATE(date_created) = DATE(last_updated)
```

The timezone may be relevant here. So you may want to cast the datetime values to the user's timezone prior to using the DATE() function, using [CONVERT_TZ()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(last_updated, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

not pretty but works:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE day(date_created) = day(last_updated) and
month(date_created) = month(last_updated) and
year(date_created) = year(last_updated)
```